# Use unity with git LFS

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, large-files, git-lfs

I'm trying to use git lfs with my unity project, but since i'm quite new to git , i'm not sure how should i make lfs track the files.

Here is a link of git ignore files i found, i suppose i should make git lfs track everything in gitignore? (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore)

But should i first git-add all the files i have in that project and then use git-lfs-track to add the files in that link to lfs?  I'm extremely new to git, so if there's someone could provide me a step by step guide would be most appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special.

Have a good read of: https://git-lfs.github.com/

```
git lfs track "*.fbx"
```

Then:

```
git add Assets/foo/megaship.fbx
git commit -m "Add model"
git push origin master
```

Git ignore is totally different. That ignores all the files in the path; they won't be committed at all.

Git lfs is a smart tracker for specially marked content items, that results in them being pushed and pulled in a special way.

To see a list of commands, just type:

```
git lfs
```

You can see the current set of tracked file types in your `.gitattributes` file, eg:

```
*.mp3 filter=lfs -text
*.MP3 filter=lfs -text
```

so, basically, this has nothing to do with your gitignore; just `git lfs install` and `git lfs track` and you should be good to go.

Specifically, you should just do this:

```
git lfs install
git lfs track "*.FILETYPE" <-- for any files you want
```

Now just use git normally.

Answer (score 0):

Use LFS with Git in Unity is not onle a good idea, is your only option if you don't want to fill your hard drive.

Without Git LFS you are storing your assets on your computer everytime you make a commit. This makes sense with code or text files, not with binaries.

If you don't use Git lfs, try SVN or any other service instead.

Comment: May I ask you, I use git LFS for unity but every time I make a change in the scene (200mb), it gets saved whole to the LFS storage with a commit. Therefore, Gitlab storage is growing like 1.5gb every week. How can I solve this ? Thanks.